# How to run 500 api requests in parallel at the same time

Tags: api, curl, load-testing, xargs

Need to stress test an api and have a requirement for 500 API requests within a second. Is there command to test this?

Was using `xargs` but the responses timestamps were not all the same, changing every 10 requests or so.

Answer (score 2):

A powerful yet simple option could be using `k6`, from the example at https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/running-k6/, simulating `500 VUs` (*virtual-users*):

### simple.js

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep } from 'k6';

export default function () {
  http.get('https://test.k6.io');
  sleep(1);
}
```

### output

```shell
$ k6 run --vus 500 --duration 1s script.js 

          /\      |‾‾| /‾‾/   /‾‾/   
     /\  /  \     |  |/  /   /  /    
    /  \/    \    |     (   /   ‾‾\  
   /          \   |  |\  \ |  (‾)  | 
  / __________ \  |__| \__\ \_____/ .io

  execution: local
     script: script.js
     output: -

  scenarios: (100.00%) 1 scenario, 500 max VUs, 31s max duration (incl. graceful stop):
           * default: 500 looping VUs for 1s (gracefulStop: 30s)


running (17.7s), 000/500 VUs, 500 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
default ✓ [======================================] 500 VUs  1s

     data_received..................: 8.5 MB 481 kB/s
     data_sent......................: 219 kB 12 kB/s
     http_req_blocked...............: avg=2.65s    min=681.15ms med=2.46s    max=13.29s   p(90)=4.62s    p(95)=5.36s   
     http_req_connecting............: avg=339.8ms  min=315.61ms med=327.35ms max=1.32s    p(90)=346.11ms p(95)=349.95ms
     http_req_duration..............: avg=1.51s    min=318ms    med=1.08s    max=10.42s   p(90)=2.84s    p(95)=3.68s   
       { expected_response:true }...: avg=1.51s    min=318ms    med=1.08s    max=10.42s   p(90)=2.84s    p(95)=3.68s   
     http_req_failed................: 0.00%  ✓ 0         ✗ 500  
     http_req_receiving.............: avg=214.48ms min=27.91µs  med=82.99µs  max=4.04s    p(90)=699.7ms  p(95)=1.3s    
     http_req_sending...............: avg=36.37µs  min=12.5µs   med=34.49µs  max=106.12µs p(90)=53.32µs  p(95)=60.42µs 
     http_req_tls_handshaking.......: avg=2.28s    min=329.4ms  med=2.08s    max=12.96s   p(90)=4.29s    p(95)=4.98s   
     http_req_waiting...............: avg=1.3s     min=315.16ms med=997.61ms max=10.1s    p(90)=2.57s    p(95)=3.4s    
     http_reqs......................: 500    28.311116/s
     iteration_duration.............: avg=5.17s    min=2.03s    med=4.83s    max=17.56s   p(90)=7.98s    p(95)=8.84s   
     iterations.....................: 500    28.311116/s
     vus............................: 1      min=1       max=500
     vus_max........................: 500    min=500     max=500
```

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to proceed with curl - take a look at [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool

However I would recommend going for a specialized load testing tool for this, the reasons are in:

1. Running 500 requests per second won't tell you the full story, the recommended approach is increasing the load **gradually** so you would be able to correlate increasing load with response time, number of hits per second and other metrics
2. You will get basic pass/fail criteria i.e. response status code checking out of the box
3. You will get statistical tables and charts out of the box
4. In case you will need to extend the script later on (i.e. extract something from response to build the next request or apply custom pass/fail criteria)

The most advanced free and open source load testing tools are:

- [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

More information on the above tools including features comparison: [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) command.

```
ab -n 500 https://apihost/api/action
ab -n 500 -c 10 https://apihost/api/action
```